# Call a service in SuperClass whose implementation is injected in subclass

Tags: java, inheritance, cdi, weld

I'm using Weld for Cdi in a JavaSE application.
Some of my services come in two flavors. Distinction in CDI via `Qualifier` (`@Italian` or `@Chinese`). 
Most service code is located in a a shared superclass. 
This superclass uses other services. Those with a common implementation are simply injected in the superclass (`TimerService`).
But if there is a specific implementation, it depends on the subclass which implementation is to be chosen.
In the example below: When `ItalianFoodController` is calling `service.cookSoup()`, it should use an Italian recipe for the soup...

```
public abstract class FoodService {
    @Inject TimerService timerService;

    abstract protected RecipeService getRecipeService();

    protected void cookSoup() {
        getRecipeService().getSoupRecipe();
        timerService.setTimer(20);
        ...
    }
}

@ApplicationScoped @Italian
public class ItalianFoodService extends FoodService {
    @Inject @Italian RecipeService recipeService;

    @Override
    protected RecipeService getRecipeService() {
        return recipeService;
    }
    ...
}

@ApplicationScoped @Chinese
public class ChineseFoodService extends FoodService {
    @Inject @Chinese RecipeService recipeService;
    ...
}

public class ItalianFoodController {
    @Inject @Italian ItalianFoodService service;
    ...
    public void cook() {
        service.cookSoup();
    }
}
```

The example is working fine.
**My question is: Is there a CDI-pattern to get rid of `getRecipeService()`?**
The most intuitiv approach would be:

```
public abstract class FoodService {
    @Inject RecipeService recipeService;
    ...    
}
public class ItalianFoodService extends FoodService {
    @Inject @Italian RecipeService recipeService;
    ...    
}
```

But this does not work because recipeService will be hidden but not overridden by the subclass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thinking about @maress' answer I came up with a different approach which allows me to use the injected service quite intuitively.

**Solution using constructor injection:**

```
public abstract class FoodService {
    protected RecipeService recipeService;

    FoodService (RecipeService recipeService) {
        this.recipeService = recipeService;
    }
}

public class ItalianFoodService extends FoodService {
    // Only needed if ItalianRecipeService holds additional methods.
    @Inject @Italian ItalianRecipeService recipeService;

    @Inject
    ItalianFoodService(@Italian RecipeService recipeService) {
       super(recipeService);
    }
}
```

Alternatively the same can be achieved via

**Solution using @PostConstruct:**

```
public abstract class FoodService {
    protected RecipeService recipeService;
}

public class ItalianFoodService extends FoodService {
    // Only needed if ItalianRecipeService holds additional methods.
    @Inject @Italian ItalianRecipeService recipeService;

    @PostConstruct
    postConstruct() {
       super.recipeService = recipeService;
    }
}
```

Both solutions are quite short and readable while the one with constructor injection is slightly more explizit about the injection.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is, and it is called `Instance.select(qualifier)`. And this is how it will work:

```
public abstract class FoodService {

    @Inject
    TimerService timerService;

    @Any
    @Inject
    Instance<RecipeService> recipeServices;

    private final Annotation recipeSelector;

    FoodService(){
        //this is just one way you can get hold of the qualifier for each soup service
        // another way is to look into AnnotationLiteral
        recipeSelector = Arrays.stream(getClass().getDeclaredAnnotations())
        .filter((ann) -> annot.annotationType().isAnnotationPresent(Qualfiier.class))
        .findFirst()
        .orElseThrow(()-> new someexception());
    }

    protected void cookSoup() {
        RecipeService service = recipeServices.select(recipeSelector).get().getSoupRecipe();
        timerService.setTimer(20);
    }
}
```

More details on this:
http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/2.0/cdi-spec.html#dynamic_lookup
and
http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/2.0/cdi-spec.html#annotationliteral_typeliteral

Comment: Thx for you're idea about dealing with the qualifier in the constructor. It lead me to a different approach (see answer below). I use Instance<> sometimes if I need multiple CDI-instances. But in this case it doesn't help me to make the code more readable as in my first approach.